# Append list as element to an empty numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to append a list as an element to an empty numpy array, but when i try the following each element of the list is added individually. I'm using a simplified example which can still answer my question i believe.

```
arr = np.array([])
                 
ls = [1,2,3,7]

arr = np.append(arr,ls)
```

which gives the following result.

```
print(arr[0])
1
```

The desired result would be:

```
print(arr[0])
[1,2,3,7]
```

Also, i cannot try something like this since i run out of ram when using regular python lists.

```
arr = []
arr.append(ls)
arr = np.array(arr)
```

Another attempt was this which still yield the same results.

```
arr = np.zeros(shape=(0,1))                 
ls = [1,2,3,7]
arr = np.append(arr,ls)
print(arr[0])
1
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Appending to `numpy` arrays is computationally expensive in the long run since `numpy` needs to allocate new array (memory) for the concatenated array, copy the items from the old array to the new array, then finally copy the to be appended array to the new array. I suggest you avoid using `np.append`. I see that you run into memory issues using `list.append`, however if you store each `ls` as `numpy` arrays you should be able to save some space:

```
arr = []
ls = np.array([1,2,3])
arr.append(ls)
ls = np.array([1,2,3])
arr.append(ls)
.
.
.

arr = np.array(arr)
```

However, you can achieve your desired using `np.append` if you initalize `arr` with your first array:

```
arr = np.array([1,2,3,7])
ls = [0,1,0,1]
arr = np.stack([arr, ls])

print(arr[0])
#[1,2,3,7]
print(arr[1])
#[0,1,0,1]
```

If you do know the upper bound `N` of items you want in the array, and that you have same sized arrays of length `d`, you can pre-initialize memory. For example if `N=2` and `d=3`:

```
N = 2
d = 3

arr = np.empty((N,d))
arr[0] = [1,2,3]
arr[1] = [4,5,6]

print(arr[0])
#[[1, 2, 3],
# [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: Hello, Naphat thank you for your response. N is unknown, and d = 1 which would be a list that holds other elements.

Comment: Also, i've tried what you proposed above (in the new edit) already and i still run out of memory

Comment: Isn't `d=4` in your example?

Comment: ls is a single element

Comment: `ls = [1,2,3,4]` is 4 element list right? It also seems that you want to `arr` to act like shape `(-1,4)`, since you desire `arr[0] = [1,2,3,4]`, hence my thought that `d=4`.

Comment: shape will be (N,1) where 1 is ls in this case

Comment: Ah I see, my mistake

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232802/discussion-between-naphat-amundsen-and-olive-yew).

Answer (score 0):

With a small example like this, examining the whole array will be more instructive than `arr[0]`.

```
In [1]: arr = np.array([])
   ...: ls = [1,2,3,7]
   ...: arr1 = np.append(arr,ls)
In [2]: arr1
Out[2]: array([1., 2., 3., 7.])
```

The `np.append` action is just:

```
In [3]: np.concatenate([arr, np.array(ls)])
Out[3]: array([1., 2., 3., 7.])
```

It's just an alternative way of calling `concatenate`.  It make some sense when adding one value to an existing array, as in `np.append(np.array([1,2,3]), 4)`. Otherwise it is more of a problem than a solution.  It is **not** a list append clone.

`np.array([])` is not a clone of `[]` either.  But your use of that plus the `arr=np.append(arr,ls)` assignment, suggests you are trying to clone the common list append loop.

Many other SO stress that repeated use of `np.append` (or anything in the `np.concatenate` family) is inefficient.  Each use requires a full copy.  At least temporarily you'll have the original `arr` and the new one, which is a bit bigger.

You say that building a list of arrays, and doing one `np.concatenate` (or variant) at the end will push your memory limits.  As best I can reason the repeated `concatenates` will do the same.  However, I haven't tried to test this; I don't like to intentionally create a memory error.

Here's a way of doing what you initially tried to do with `append`:

```
In [4]: arr = np.array([None,None],dtype=object)
In [5]: arr[0] = [1,2,3,7]
In [6]: arr[1] = np.array([1,2,3,7])
In [7]: arr
Out[7]: array([list([1, 2, 3, 7]), array([1, 2, 3, 7])], dtype=object)
In [8]: arr[0]
Out[8]: [1, 2, 3, 7]
```

An object dtype array is much closer to a list in nature.  It too stores references, rather than values.  But it doesn't have any of the computational benefits of a numeric dtype array.

You also tried:

```
In [11]: arr = np.zeros((0,1))
In [12]: arr
Out[12]: array([], shape=(0, 1), dtype=float64)
In [13]: np.append(arr, [1,2,3,7])
Out[13]: array([1., 2., 3., 7.])
```

Same thing as the original, except the starting array is different.  But `np.append` docs, **if we take time to read them**, tell us that it ravels the inputs - unless we provide an axis.  `np.ravel(arr)` is just `np.array([])`!

But if we just throw in an axis value like 0, we get `concatenate` dimension errors:

```
In [19]: np.append(arr, [1,2,3,7],axis=0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-19-a30d55b63eca>", line 1, in <module>
    np.append(arr, [1,2,3,7],axis=0)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in append
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 4745, in append
    return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in concatenate
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)
```

This traceback shows how the `append` is translated into a `concatenate`.

If we want to add a 4 element array to a "empty" we have to start with the right shape:

```
In [21]: arr = np.zeros((0,4))
In [22]: np.vstack([arr,[1,2,3,7]])
Out[22]: array([[1., 2., 3., 7.]])
```

`vstack` is another `concatenate` front end, one that will turn the `[1,2,3,7]` into a `np.array([[1,2,3,7]])`, with shape (1,4).  Now a (0,4) can be joined with a (1,4) to make a (1,4).

So not only is repeated `concatenate` slower, it requires that we get the initial array just right. Despite its superficial similarity to list append, `np.append` does not allow us to ignore array dimensions and what `np.concatenate` requires.